# Is there any way to switch multiple cursors with tab?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

The situation is: in my html-file I have a lot of "href" attributes to be filled with specific links. And I can get multiple cursors on every needed place.(via Ctrl+D, or Alt+Enter).

Now it would be very helpful if I could switch between this cursors with tab(like emmet plugin does with self-generated html-content, if you know what I'm talking about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multi cursor, and switch between them in using :

```
Ctrl + F3
```

or

```
Ctrl + Shift + F3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the behavior I believe you want by selecting all the "href" attributes using ctrl+d. If you are selecting all of them, you cna run the `find_all_under` command (alt + f3 in windows, unsure of other platforms but you can search for the command). Then, bookmark the cursor positions (ctrl+f2 in windows). You can then use f2 to cycle through the bookmarks. You could bind the appropriate command to tab if you want also, though you would have to do some work do you don't break normal tab behavior.

As a side note, I believe emmet simply inserts a snippet, so it defines various locations for the cursor to jump to through the built in snippet behavior.

@Jahnux solution may be more ideal since you wouldn't have to select initially, but I believe you would have to move the cursor back to the "href" attribute for continuing to the next token.

You may also want to investigate simply using the find functionality, though perhaps you have run into some limitations with that.